# Email is is not getting validated in bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am looking for an input which has to take only email addresses as the input, however it is allowing any input. I want the input box to be focused as danger until it is a valid email address. It should show an alert message if it is not a proper email address.

```
<input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email Id"
  id="customerRegistrationEmailId" data-toggle="tooltip"
  data-placement="top" title="Enter Email Id" />
```

Comment: Are you using any JavaScript library? If so, which ones? They would make this task a lot simpler

Comment: I am bit confused which are all the libraries to be added.Could you please tell me which are all the libraries to be added.

Comment: Bootstrap by defauld doesn't have validation included, but you have some plugins for that - [like this one](http://1000hz.github.io/bootstrap-validator/).

Comment: Did you use HTML5?

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="email" name="email" required
  ng-class = "{'redborder':errortemp||email.shwerr,'greenborder':contactform.email.$valid}"
  ng-click = "errortemp = false;email.click=true;"
  ng-model="userdata.email" autocomplete="off"
  ng-pattern = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/' >
```

In the controller:

```
$scope.errortemp = false;
if(!userdata.email.$invalid){
    $scope.temp=True
}
```

Comment: Where does it say that the OP uses angular?